# Why is substring() function in returning a value when it should be returning an overflow message

Tags: java, string

I am trying to solve a problem which goes like this:-

Given a string, return a "rotated left 2" version where the first 2 chars are moved to the end. The string length will be at least 2.

```
left2("Hello") → "lloHe"
left2("java") → "vaja"
left2("Hi") → "Hi"
```

I have written two functions for this:-

```
    public String left2(String str)
    {
         String str1 = str;
          if(str.length()>2)
           str1 = str.substring(2)+str.substring(0,2);
         return str1;
    }

    public String left2(String str)
    {
         return str.substring(2)+str.substring(0,2);
    }
```

Both of the functions are correct. I wanted to know that if the first parameter of `substring()` function is an index, then am I not getting an `overflow` error in the second function? I am asking this because Java doesn't end in a NULL character so I think there be an error in the second function.

Comment: From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29: "*Throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.*"

Comment: Did you try passing a one-character or an empty string?

Comment: @kusur This link explains everything http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233379/substringstartindex-endindex-why-index-out-of-range-is-not-thrown

Comment: When you do `str.substring(2)`on `"hi"`, it gets the substring starting at the position right after the "i" and ending at the end of the string aka, empty space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your Substring logic works only if the text length is greater than 2. See here:

```
    if(str.length()>2)
       str1 = str.substring(2)+str.substring(0,2);
```

This is the source code for `substring` method in java:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
     if (beginIndex < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
     }
     if (endIndex > count) {
          throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
     }
     if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
           throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex);
     }
     return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
           new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}
```

From experience, documentation may lie, but code doesn't. `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown only if

- a. beginIndex is less than 0(that is, is negative) or
- b. endIndex is greater than count or
- c. beginIndex is greater than endIndex.

Comment: I am talking about the second function.

Comment: @kusur I have included the source code for substring, that should tell you exactly when `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is raised.

Comment: Are these conditions applied to `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` as well?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the second function

```
return str.substring(2)+str.substring(0,2);
```

works is that you never tried passing a string that is shorter than two characters. If you did, you would have received an exception ([demo](http://ideone.com/pmNyNS)).

The reason this works when you pass a string of two characters is that the index that you pass is allowed to be equal to the length of the string (in this case, `2`). When you pass an index that equals the length of the string to `substring` that takes one parameter, you get an empty string. When you pass an index that equals the length of the string to two-parameter `substring`, it takes the string up to and including the last character.