# substring(int) method magically doesn't throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Why does `"a".substring(1)` not `throw` `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, while it does for index that is >= 2? It is really interesting.

Answer (score 5):

you will get answer in source code  :

```
 public String substring(int beginIndex) {
        if (beginIndex < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
        }
        int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
        if (subLen < 0) {
            throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
        }
        return (beginIndex == 0) ? this : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
    }
```

where `value.length` will get 1 in your condition so

```
int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
```

which will become like :

```
int subLen = 1 - 1;
```

and `subLen` will be 0 so  `if (subLen < 0) {` will be false and it wont throw exception :)

Comment: That's the answer I needed to see, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

[Behaves as specified in the JavaDoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

> **Throws**: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if `beginIndex` is *negative or
>   larger* than the length of this String object.

Also, from the examples in the JavaDoc:

> `"emptiness".substring(9)` returns `""` (an empty string)

Therefore, `"a".substring(1)` returns an empty string, as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Because you get an empty string back i.e, `""`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("a".substring(1).equals("")); // substring --> from index 1 upto length of "a" (which is also 1)
```

}

O/P :

```
true
```

You get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when the int argument is greater that length of the String.

example :

`System.out.println("a".substring(2).equals("")); // throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

`a.substring(1)` returns an empty string which is why it does not throw an exception as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233379/substringstartindex-endindex-why-index-out-of-range-is-not-thrown) question. `String.substring(n)` only fails if n is greater than the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what `substring()` does.

```
 public String substring(int beginIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return (beginIndex == 0) ? this : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

`int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;` if `subLen<0` exception will throw. In your case that won't happen.

In your case `value.length=1` and `beginIndex=1` then `1-1=0`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("a".substring(1).equals("")); 
}

You got that from the source code but one point to think is why java has :

You get StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when the int argument is greater that length of the String.


why not throw exception when int argument is equal to length of string because...

String substring(int fromindex); <-prototype

There is no point of NOT throwing exception for int argument '1' as String length is 1 and you are searching from second index..

can anyone give reason?
```